# посоветуйте как сделать кластеризацию (одномерного) списка целых чисел без заданого количества кластеров и вычислить коэффициент кластеризации

Tags: python, анализ, кластеризация, данные

имеется список целых чисел (например от 0 do 32)

1. нужно разделить на кластеры. количество кластеров неизвестно. максимум 4.
2. вычислить коэффициент кластеризации (я назвал его xi)

Вообще-то это нужно для определения похожести наборов картинок из которых получаются числа(число пятен, углы наклона, длинны линий...)

Например:

1. если в одном наборе количество пятен [2,3,3,3,5,5] а в другом [12,12,12,13,14,14] - то видно, что в первом мало пятен, а во втором много
2. если в одном наборе количество пятен [10,12,12,14,14,15] а в другом [16,17,19,20,20,22] - то количество пятен не очень отличается, хотя во втором наборе больше...

хотелось бы разделить числа, максимум на 4 кластера, и вычислить коэффициент, который бы характеризовал кучность кластера, расстояние между кластерами...

я нарисовал гистограммы и примерно задал кэффициент кластеризации (по своему разумению)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Кластеризуйте на разное число кластеров, вычисляйте `silhouette_score`. Где максимум его - то число кластеров и оптимальное. Примерно такой может быть код:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.metrics import silhouette_score
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

for data in [list(range(6,10))*5 + list(range(22,26))*5, list(range(2,6))*5 + list(range(12,16))*5 + list(range(22,30))*5]:
    clusters = list(range(2, 5))
    scores = []
    clusters_centers = []
    for k in clusters:
        kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=k).fit(list(zip(data)))
        preds = kmeans.predict(list(zip(data)))
        clusters_centers.append(kmeans.cluster_centers_)
        scores.append(silhouette_score(list(zip(data)), preds))

    s, k = max(zip(scores, clusters))

    plt.figure();
    sns.displot(data, bins=32);
    for x in clusters_centers[clusters.index(k)]:
        plt.plot([x[0],x[0]], [0,5], c='r', linestyle='--')

    plt.figure();
    sns.lineplot(clusters, scores);
    plt.xlabel("Число кластеров");
    plt.ylabel('silhouette_score');
    plt.xticks(clusters);


    plt.title(f'Максимальная мера {s:.3f} при {k} кластерах');
    plt.plot(k, s, 'r*')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: годный вариант на крайний случай. но по-моему, kmeans - для одномерного массива - слишком затрано. Две проблемы - долго работает и есть вероятность неоднозначности результата.  думаю насчет сглаживания и поиска  минимумов.

Comment: нашел алгоритм MeanShift 
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.MeanShift.html#sklearn.cluster.MeanShift
 в ответе
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51487549/unsupervised-learning-clustering-1d-array?noredirect=1&lq=1 работает намного быстрее K-Means  (почти в 15 раз быстрее)

Comment: Прикольно, не знал про такой.